# ASCII-art unicorn one-liner

Tags: debug, ascii, ascii-art

I need to spruce up my debugging messages. I have a smiley in there `:D`, but someone suggested using a unicorn. There are some nice resources on ASCII unicorns (e.g. http://www.ascii-art.de/ascii/uvw/unicorn.txt), but these are all too large to fit on one line. How should I go about writing in a small ASCII unicorn?

Comment: lol, this is such a silly and off-topic question. it was worth it for the herd of unicorns, though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are my attempts:

```
  ~nn°'    `°nn~       ~m°'    `°m~
  ~nn"'    `"nn~       ~m"'    `"m~
  ~nnº'    `ºnn~       ~mº'    `ºm~
  ~nnº¯    ¯ºnn~       ~mº¯    ¯ºm~
  ~nn^'    `^nn~       ~m^'    `^m~
```

Note: ° (degree), º (masculine ordinal indicator), and ¯ (macron) aren't ASCII.

Comment: hehe awesome looks like you have a herd of unicorns! each slightly different, which makes sense too

Answer (score 6):

I've been trying! Haha! Believe meee! I can't find any, but how about some other single line pictures?

Like a fish:

```
><((('>
```

or a snail:

```
@/`
```

or a spider:

```
//\O/\\
```

or a caterpillar:

```
OOOOó
```

or just something like:

```
٩(͡๏̯͡๏)۶
(>n_n)># (Debug line number indicator? :D)
```

Comment: oo yes intriguing results! i'll have to work those in somehow.

Comment: @Claudiu Even added a few more ;D!

Comment: mm that is a brilliant confused face, i have to admit! but is not strict ascii sadly

Comment: @Claudiu Aww I forgot! Darn! I'd love to see a debug log of yours when it's done! haha!

Comment: <===>\\_---^--- - USS Enterprise :)

Answer (score 2):

Star Wars fan?  Here's an AT-AT:

> @@

<sub><sub>* rimshot *</sub></sub>

Answer (score 1):

This sort of looks like an upside-down unicorn, if you squint enough:

```
,eU=U.
```